# How many solutions exist to $\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \theta \right) = 2 \cos \left(2 \theta\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Hi All:  The question is quite straightforward:

> How many solutions exist to
> this trig relation?
> $$\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \theta \right) = 2 \cos \left(2 \theta\right)$$

I'm aware of the existence of half angle and double angle formulae but I still couldn't figure out how to use them  to figure that out.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Specifically, show your work and thoughts on the problem.

Comment: @jjagmath I'm curious -- in what way is this question of particularly low quality? There are many, many more worse. I thought this one was actually quite good.

Comment: @PrimeMover Look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Specifically, as I say in my previous comment, the OP didn't show any work on the problem. By the way, just because there are worse questions doesn't make this one a good one.

Comment: Is $\theta$ between like $0$ and $2\pi$? Because otherwise there would clearly be an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Thanks for your comment. I agree that I should have shown some work. But that means that it's a poorly worded question and not necessarily a poor question. :).  In fact, the two answers below don't seem to jive so maybe it's not as easy as it looks at first glance ?

Comment: @MathMagician: We can restrict between $0$ and $2\pi$ since that simplifies things. In that case, I can just count the number of times the difference between the two functions crosses zero which is fine. But that requires plotting and I was hoping-thinking that there was a way to do it without plotting. Also, is there something wrong with the approach that Yang WeiFei took ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Path of least resistance, while attractive (and in fact rational) on the part 
of the question poster, isn't going to do well at mathSE. 
See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The left hand side has period $4 \pi$ the right hand side has period $\pi$.  So if $\theta$ is a solution, so is $\theta + 4k\pi$ for any integer $k$,  so your answer has to either be 0 solutions or an infinite number of solutions.

Now you can just look at $\sin(\frac 1 2 \theta)-2\cos (2\theta)$.  If that is always negative or always positive, you have no solution.  If you can find one positive and one negative, then somewhere it is 0 in between by continuity and you have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Please, avoid answering low quality questions, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: @Alan:  Thanks. I plotted it and it definitely crosses zero so that would mean that there is an infinite number of solutions. Thanks for that insight. But I still have some confusion because does that not contradict the result that Wang YeFei came up with ? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that there is not a  contradiction between the answers of Alan and Wang YeFei because, if the domain is restricted to between 0 and $2 \pi$, then there are 4 solutions. If the domain is not restricted themselves to between $0$ and $2 \pi$, then there are an infinite number of solutions. Thanks to those who helped me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x = \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\implies x = 2(-1+2\cos^2\theta)= -2+4(1-2\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2}))^2=-2+4(1-2x^2)^2=-2+4-16x^2+16x^4\implies 16x^4-16x^2-x+2=0$. Wolfram Alpha says the roots are all irrational numbers.

Comment: Please, avoid answering low quality questions, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: Wang YeFei: Thanks for your help. My comment to Alan is the same to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Wang YeFei: I used uniroot in R for four different ranges ( based on the plot of the function  between zero and 2 $\pi$ ) and the roots I got back were 0.2224986 pi,  0.8298339 * pi, 1.169789 pi and 1.777124 pi.  So, it seems like these are the 4 solutions if one restricts the domain to be between zero and $2 \pi$. Still, I like your technique because it doesn't require the plot of the function.